# How do I correctly add mixes of different interfaces to different classes in C#?

Tags: c#, interface

I am trying to develop an API for some assessment software that will allow me to create questions consisting of the question text, multiple choice text and the choice index of the correct answer.

All questions are worth 10 points and the question can only be answered once.

For QuestionTypeA however, the user can change the number of retries and QuestionTypeB, the user can change both the number of retries and the score.

The reason for the CommonFunctions interface is so that I don't have to duplicate QuestionText, AddChoice and SetAnswer in each of the QuestionType interfaces.

But this does then leave me with empty interfaces, which I am not sure is correct?

Also, to instantiate an object I have to write

```
QuestionTypeA QTA = (QuestionTypeA)new Question();
```

I would rather the Question class dealt with the cast so that the user can then just type:

```
QuestionTypeA QTA = new Question();
```

How can achieve this?

Thanks
Andrew

```
public interface IRetryable
{
    int Retries { set; get; }
}

public interface IScoreable
{
    int Score { set; get; }
}

public interface CommmonFunctions
{
    string QuestionText { set; get; }
    void AddChoice(string ChoiceText);
    int SetAnswer { set; get; }
}

public interface QuestionTypeA : CommmonFunctions, IRetryable
{

}

public interface QuestionTypeB : CommmonFunctions, IRetryable, IScoreable
{

}

public interface QuestionTypeC : CommmonFunctions
{

}

class Question : CommmonFunctions
{
    private List<string> Choices;

    public Question()
    {
        Choices = new List<string>();
        Retries = 1;
        Score = 10;
    }

    public string QuestionText { set; get; }
    public void AddChoice(string ChoiceText)
    {
        Choices.Add(ChoiceText);
    }
    public int SetAnswer { set; get; }

    public int Retries { set; get; }
    public int Score { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you reading about decorator pattern

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are over-thinking things...

Just keep it simple.

var question1 = new QuestionTypeA();
var question2 = new QuestionTypeB();

```
public interface IRetryable
{
    int Retries { set; get; }
}

public interface IScoreable
{
    int Score { set; get; }
}

public abstract class Question
{
    private List<string> choices = new List<string>();

    public string QuestionText { set; get; }

    public int SetAnswer { set; get; }

    public void AddChoice(string choiceText)
    {
        choices.Add(choiceText);
    }
}

public class QuestionTypeA : Question, IRetryable
{
    public QuestionTypeA()
    {
        Retries = 1;
    }

    public int Retries { set; get; }
}

public class QuestionTypeB : Question, IScoreable
{
    public QuestionTypeB()
    {
        Score = 0;
    }

    public int Score { set; get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since all question have at least score 10 and 0 or more retries, why not include that info in the common interface like this?

```
    public interface CommmonFunctions
    {
        string QuestionText { set; get; }
        void AddChoice(string ChoiceText);
        int SetAnswer { set; get; }
        int Score { set; get; }
        bool ScoreReadonly {get;}
        int Retries { set; get; }
        bool RetriesReadonly  {get;}
    }
```

`ScoreReadonly` and `RetriesReadonly` show if score or retries count can be changed outside class:

```
    class Question : CommmonFunctions
    {
        private List<string> Choices;

        public Question()
        {
            Choices = new List<string>();
            _retries = 1;
            _score = 10;
        }

        public string QuestionText { set; get; }
        public void AddChoice(string ChoiceText)
        {
            Choices.Add(ChoiceText);
        }
        public int SetAnswer { set; get; }

        private int _retries;
        public int Retries 
        { 
            get{ return _retries; }
            set 
            {
                if (!RetriesReadonly)
                    _retries = value;
            }
        }

        private int _score;
        public int Score 
        { 
            get{ return _score; }
            set 
            {
                if (!ScoreReadonly)
                    _score = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual bool ScoreReadonly {get{return false;}}
        public virtual bool RetriesReadonly {get{return false;}}
    }
```

UPDATE

```
    public interface IShuffable
    {
         void Shuffle();
    }

    class QuestionTypeA : Question, IShuffable
    {
        // question of type A can't change score
        public override bool ScoreReadonly { get {return true;}}

        public void Shuffle()
        {
          // Code to implement shuffling the choices
        }
    }

    class QuestionTypeB : Question {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ASh for your response.
I guess it would make sense to incorporate in them in to the interface.

I now need to add another interface (IShuffle) to QuestionTypeA as below.

```
interface IShuffable
{
    void Shuffle();
}

public class QuestionTypeA : Question, IRetryable, IShuffable
{
    public QuestionTypeA()
    {
        Retries = 1;
    }

    public int Retries { set; get; }
    public void Shuffle()
    {
        // Code to implement shuffling the choices
    }
}
```

Shuffle has nothing to do with QuestionType B or C, so Ideally I would like to hide this method from instances of QuestionType B and C so that it doesn't appear in intellisense.

Any attempt to call the shuffle method on instances of either QuestionTypeB or C, should then result in a standard compiler error i.e "QuestionTypeB does not contain a definition for shuffle ...".

Would it be better to use interfaces for this solution given the above? or something else?

Thanks Andrew